# Edit code on local machine in Intellij IDE, push result to AWS instance to run

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea

Is there a way to edit code on my local machine in Intellij IDE and then put the result to a running instance of AWS?

I've seen some plugins, such as [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-install.html), but I'm not sure that's exactly the right tool.

Does anyone know a good approach to solve this challenge?

Comment: There are different ways of "putting" your code on AWS, try to be more spesific

Comment: maybe like, I save it and it updates to my server, is it possible?

Comment: You could try this feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/deploying-your-application.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is to set up a `Continuous Delivery Pipeline` (see details here: https://aws.amazon.com/devops/continuous-delivery/).

You also need to use a version control system such as `Git`.

Once you have a repository linked to your pipeline *(and the instruction that deployment should happen at every change in the master branch)*, and a clone of that repository on your local machine you can make some changes and `push` to `origin master`. That will trigger the automatic deployment.

As per doing that from IntelliJ:
`VCS -> Git -> push` (or `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `K`)